# Hibernate returning null for @OneToOne

Tags: hibernate

I defined this relationship in my `User` class:

```
@OneToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn (name = "id")
    private Balance balance;
```

Hibernate creates necessary tables with the right relationships.

However, when I retrieve `User` objects using the following code, `Balance` is set `null`.

```
User fetchedUser = userRepository.findOne(id);        
Balance balance = fetchedUser.getBalance();
```

Why is this?

(I use Spring Data for data access.)

Edit:

This code generates the `users` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `contact_number` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `date_created` DATE NOT NULL,
    `date_of_birth` DATE NOT NULL,
    `device_id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `gender` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    `location` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `username` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `balance_id` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `FK6A68E08CBE6702` (`balance_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK6A68E08CBE6702` FOREIGN KEY (`balance_id`) REFERENCES `balances` (`id`)
)
```

And this generates `balances`

```
CREATE TABLE `balances` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `total_claimed` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `total_won` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Comment: Could you provide more details about your implementation? Especially how `Balance` class is mapped and how does the generated database schema look like.

Comment: I will update the code that results from using your suggested changes.

Answer (score 2):

In `@JoinColumn` annotation name references the column which stores foreign key to the other part of relationship. I can only assume, that in your mapping column `id` stores identifier (PrimaryKey) of the `User`. Maybe it should be something like:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColum(name = "balance_id" referencedColumnName = "id")
private Balance balance;
```

Above mapping will work when following requirements are met:

- column in `USERS` table pointing to associated record in `BALANCES` table is named `balance_id`
- PrimaryKey column in `BALANCES` table is named `id`

If names used in your application differ, you'll have to adjust this mapping accordingly.

Additionally maybe you want the relationship to be bidirectional. In this case you should add following mapping to `Balance` entity:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "balance")
private User user;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Blekit. The names do match and I have updated my code as you suggested but the balance field is still `null`.

Comment: Looking at generated DDL, it seems that there aren't any association between `USERS` and `BALANCES` tables (no FK definition in tables definitions). I think you should regenerate schema after fixing mappings as described below and try again.

Comment: I don't want it to be bidirectional since there isn't any need but if being bidirectional will solve my problem, I'll do it.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with your problem, it should work fine without this. Do you still get `null` after regeneration of tables?

Comment: I still do have the problem.

Comment: Are you sure, that there are actual data in the database? I mean what is in column `balance_id` in the record representing user with given `id`?

Comment: There actually is. You can see it for yourself here:
<property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://ec2-23-21-211-172.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3306/luckydb" />
<property name="username" value="innolab"/>
<property name="password" value="innopass"/>

Comment: Could you paste code where you try accessing the entities? And maybe a little bit more of both entity classes as well?

Answer (score 0):

Please add Foreign Key Constraint and then try again.

```
CREATE TABLE `balances` (
   `balance_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `total_claimed` INT(11) NOT NULL,
   `total_won` INT(11) NOT NULL,
   `user_id` BIGINT(20),
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

alter table balances add constraint XFK_USER foreign key (user_id)
  references users (id);
```

Comment: One problem that we have is we need to generate tables using code. We need permission to alter database tables.